# Bamboo plan: Compress the artifact after build and uncompress after deployment to server

Tags: node.js, continuous-deployment, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

This is my first time where I am both learning and implementing automated CICD pipelines in Atlassian bamboo. I have a NodeJS project whose build and deployment plan I configured after much R&D over the net.

In the deployment process, I observed that the deployment is taking very much time as the number of files to be transferred are more in numbers due to node_modules probably. I would like to compress the artifact generated after build steps and want to decompress at server side once the transfer is complete.

I tried finding ZIP in the tool tasks but it is not there. My question is that is it possible in any other way. Is doing it via cmd works & is feasible? 
I have a little experience over the Linux commands.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we use an Ant task including ivy to prepare, zip and publish our projects as artifacts. In the deployment we use an SCP Task to copy the artifact onto our server and an SSH task to unzip it.
So our whole build part is implemented in ant and the only thing our bamboo build does, is checking out a git repository and running the ant script.
That workflow is used for a lot of different projects including nodejs, python, java, c++ or pure text file setups and it works really well.

But a normal script task for zipping should also do the job and depending on the scale of your projects Ant may be an overkill.

Comment: Wow. This looks feasible then. Can you elaborate a bit of your build process where you generate the artifacts as zipping itself? I got your deployment SCP tasks as i did the same in my case. It would help me in a successful trial. I'm having a corporate account so i don't want failed trails to be more on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible to use win/linux commands for acheiving your requirement. you would need to write a task to compress the files you can use shell plugin or any other suitable plugin. once the artifact is sent to server you would need a pooling batch program to unzip your artifact at the server end.